# Is there a word for homonyms across languages?

Tags: translation, homonyms

For example, the words *design* in English and *Dasein* (being there) in German look similar, but mean something completely different.

Comment: I'm not sure about similar words in different languages (could you be referring to false friends?), but a type of homonyms - words that sound the same (but are spelt differently and have different meanings) are [homophones](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homophone). I also think that you need a better example, since these are neither spelt nor pronounced the same, so they aren't really *homonyms*. Or you need to rephrase the question... Welcome to the ELU :-)!

Comment: You might consider the word **gift** as a better example (German - a poison, with a capital *G*, English - a present). But you definitely need to edit the question to clarify what it is that you're asking (you can always edit your own posts, regardless of your current reputation)

Comment: As Lucky said, *design* and *Dasein* are not homonyms: they're not spelled alike, and they don't sound alike. (Well, not unless you're pronouncing one of them completely wrong.) So what exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: This question has been asked before, and much better too. [Is there a term for a foreign word that looks like an English word but has a completely different meaning?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209789/is-there-a-term-for-a-foreign-word-that-looks-like-an-english-word-but-has-a-com)

Answer (score 4):

From [MacMillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/false-cognate), a **false cognate** is

> a word in a language that looks or sounds similar to a word in another language but means something different

Another example might be *travel* in English and *travailler* in French, where the former is a synonym of *journey* while the latter means "to work."

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with [**false friends**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend)

From wikipedia:

> False friends are pairs of words or phrases in two languages or
>   dialects (or letters in two alphabets) that look or sound similar, but
>   differ significantly in meaning.
>
> The term is a shortened version of the expression "false friend of a
>   translator"
>
> **The term should be distinguished from "false cognates"**, which are similar words in different languages that appear to have a common
>   historical linguistic origin (whatever their current meaning) but
>   actually do not.

False cognates don't necessary mean different things, it's just that they appear to have same the root, while in reality they don't.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_cognate):

> As an example of false cognates, the word for "dog" in the Australian
>   Aboriginal language Mbabaram happens to be dog, although there is no
>   common ancestor or other connection between that language and English